# UIAPI retrieve picklist values for record type stopped working - returns only one value

Tags: aura, ui-api, getpicklistvalues

I have an aura component that's been working for years. It calls the uiapi to retrieve and display a multi-picklist based on the available picklist values for a specific contact record type.

Yesterday it stopped retrieving all values - it only returns one. This is a multi-picklist field, and I have over 700 unique values. The value it returns is not the first one when sorting by alphabetical order.
This isn't occurring for other fields. I checked fls and that's not an issue.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is a little embarrassing. One of my colleagues mistakenly removed all the other values from the record type.